# String literal wont have end for regex expression

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying to use this Regex

```
^((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[1-9]|)[0-9])(\.(?!$)|$)){4}$
```

to parse IPV4 addresses

I tried to put it inside a raw string literal:

```
std::regex ipv4(R"^((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[1-9]|)[0-9])(\.(?!$)|$)){4}$");
```

but I'm getting error:

```
main.cpp:14:4: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
  }
```

because the compiler can't find the end of the string literal. What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't I simply put things inside `R""`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if you look at the reference for [string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), you'll see that the minimal raw string literal needs to be `R"()"`.

You can have additional delimiters between the `"` and the `(`, which must match the delimiters between `)` and `"`. e.g. `R"~~(hello world)~~"` contains the string literal "hello world".

Comment: Best reference on the net.